# missing the end of my app's screen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

ok I am using a RelativeLayout, my problem is that when I run my app the bottom part of the screen is missing . here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ff457670">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="163.3dp"
    android:id="@+id/currentStreak"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Right:"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="#ff22202e"
    android:textColorLink="#ffffffff"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="21.7dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="148.9dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" Wrong:"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="#ff22202e"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:id="@+id/Wrong" />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/number8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="332.2dp"
    android:layout_height="61.9dp"
    android:background="#f0000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/Spinner"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55.6dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/currentStreak" />
   <EditText
    android:layout_width="332.2dp"
    android:layout_height="55.9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55.6dp"
    android:background="#f0000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/Spinner2"
    android:layout_below="@id/Spinner"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/EnterB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Spinner2"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Enter"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_width="384.4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff22202e"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Play a Note"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_width="384.5dp"
    android:layout_height="53.5dp"
    android:background="#ff22202e"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/EnterB" />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="391.2dp"
    android:id="@+id/blank"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="#ff457670"
    android:layout_below="@id/myButton"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

what am I doing wrong? I can see the whole screen in Xamarin Studio but not when I run the code... it shows the last button but then the screen is cut off. it so not show the last TextView

Comment: Is your theme including title bar or screen resolution in your target device is less than the layout's combined height?

Comment: I am using a Galaxy Nexus( 4.65",720  x 1280: xhdpi) emulator

Answer (score 2):

The relative layout needs to have the views laid out *relative* to others.  It looks like everything is going to be stacked on top of each other in the upper left hand corner.  You need to use these layout attributes in your XML layout so that things get positioned appropriately:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Or if you just want them one on top of another, use the LinearLayout instead:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Comment: Also, you probably want to avoid some of those dip measurements that you have there.  Are you using some GUI tool to organize your layout?  Try this too:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_relative_layout.htm